# Как кликнуть по точке в Selenium чтобы отработало событие клика на objectManager?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, selenium

Очевидно, что по координатам клик не работает, как и по xpath. Пытаюсь через JS эмулировать клик, но непонятно какой target передать.

Вот таким способом навешиваю обработчик клика на метку.

```
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (event) {
//some manipulations objectManager.objects.getById(event.get('objectId')).properties.data
}
```

Вот так задаю триггер клика:

```
objectManager.objects.events.fire('click', {
    coordPosition: objectManager.objects.getById("1031").geometry.coordinates,
    target: objectManager.objects.getObjectManager().objects
})
```

Здесь, непонятно, что должно быть в target. В примерах видел объект placemark, но у меня нет нигде placemark, в глобальной области только карта и objectmanager. Я отловил событие клика реального и вот эта конструкция `objectManager.objects.getObjectManager().objects` даёт максимально похожий объект. Однако, event.get('objectId') тут не будет

Answer (score 1):

Я пошёл другим путём. Организовал доступ через класс Actions. Дальше будет код на Python:

```
map_div = self.find_element(MainPageLocators.LOCATOR_POINT_ON_MAP_IN_FOOTER)
action_chains = ActionChains(self.driver)
action_chains.move_to_element_with_offset(map_div, 588, 152).click().perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
return self.find_element(MainPageLocators.LOCATOR_TEXT_POINT_ON_MAP).text
```

p.s. мне необходим был доступ к тексту пункта, сразу после клика по point'у на карте. Координаты вычислил путём исследования скриншота в paint.

- MainPageLocators.LOCATOR_POINT_ON_MAP_IN_FOOTER - слой, где лежит яндекс карта
- MainPageLocators.LOCATOR_TEXT_POINT_ON_MAP - абсолютный путь XPATH до pop-up окошка пункта на яндекс карте после клика на фишке, где лежит адрес.